# Alternative to using ng-init in 'view'?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a 'like' function for my app. I want to be able to set the value of a dynamically generated number as the 'like count'. The problem comes in using 'ng-init', as the documentation says this is a bad way to do it!

How do you set the value in the 'controller' rather than the 'view'?

Here is what I have so far:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <article ng-repeat="feed in feeds">
    <h3>{{feed.createdby}}</h3>
    <p>{{feed.content}}</p>
    <button ng-click="likeClicked($index)">{{isLiked[$index]|liked}}</button>
    <span ng-init="likeCount=feed.likes.length">{{likeCount}}</span>
  </article>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,

JP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change

```html
`<span ng-init="likeCount=feed.likes.length">{{likeCount}}</span>`
```

per

```html
`<span>{{feed.likes.length}}</span>`.
```

If you still need the count in the controller for some other reason (which I can't see), create a controller, let's assume `FeedCtrl`, and add it to your `article`:

```html
<article ng-repeat="feed in feeds" ng-controller="FeedCtrl">
  ...
  <span>{{likeCount}}</span>
</article>
```

And your FeedCtrl would be:

```js
function FeedCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.$watch('feed.likes.length', function(newValue) {
    $scope.likeCount = newValue;
  });
}
```

Yet another approach would be create a function to resolve you the value:

```html
<article ng-repeat="feed in feeds" ng-controller="FeedCtrl">
  ...
  <span>{{likeCount()}}</span>
</article>
```

```js
function FeedCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.likeCount = function() {
    return $feed && $feed.likes ? $feed.likes.length : undefined;
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I prefer the second approach, which I have chucked in a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/aHyxJFXVrwIGb27iK45Q?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It's `$scope.feed`. Fixed. Also note the `return` I missed in the first place.

Comment: No worries. I have chucked this back in to the Plunker and I still can't get it to return a value. This has been the issue every time I have tried to retrieve anything using the approach $scope.feed.likes. It will return $scope.feed, just doesn't like the 'likes'! http://plnkr.co/edit/aHyxJFXVrwIGb27iK45Q

Comment: Even when I try this: $scope.likeCount = function() {
    return $scope.feed && $scope.feed.likes ? $scope.feed.likes.length : undefined;
  }; - Doesn't return anything.

Comment: Two issues: you wrote `$feed` instead of `$scope.feed`. And you forgot the part of creating a new controller, the `FeedCtrl`. Take a look http://plnkr.co/edit/9sGNu5WGQefKtEl4SIg7?p=preview. Finally, I would probably move the `likeClicked` to the `FeedCtrl`.

Answer (score 0):

If your **feeds** object/array is long, it's better to use **ng-bind** for performance reasons.

```
<span ng-bind="likeCount"></span>
```

rather than

```
{{likeCount}}
```