# Angular Directive - Contents of a div change

Tags: xml, events, angularjs, xslt

I am new to Angular and trying to resist mixing in jQuery to solve a problem. We are working on a reasonably complex web app using XML/XSLT, and part of that process will update a particular DIV with some information extracted from the XML and rendered as JSON. Once various changes to the XML document happen, the JSON representation of that data is updated. So I want to add a directive/event listener which fires when this content is changed and runs a method. I basically want something like this:

```
<div class="LegJsonStructure" np-change="alert('run the json push')"></div>
```

But I understand `np-change` only works with input fields. Does anyone know an Angular way of achieving this, or shall I resort to using jQuery?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Do you know about scope.$watch ?

Comment: It's not clear to me how your `<div>` is interfacing with your JSON data, nor why you need to generate JSON from XML at all. Couldn't you just consume the XML directly?

Comment: Your div should not be the one notiying of a change, he only presents the data. If I understood correctly I suggest you attach a member that the div will bind to, then bind to the member changing

Comment: Bemmu - can you point me towards an example showing how to watch for changes to a DOM element?

Comment: Eran H - can you please expand on your comment? Thanks.

Comment: We need more info in order to help you out readikus, its not clear what you are trying to accomplish here.  Can you provide a process flow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to using ng-init in 'view'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168259/alternative-to-using-ng-init-in-view)